# Integrating boilerplate themes with magento

Tags: theme, ce-1.9.0.1, html

Has anybody dealt with integrating boiler plate themes in magento? Here are some links:
- [waterlee-boilerplate](https://github.com/zeljkoprsa/waterlee-boilerplate)
- [magento boilerplate](http://magentoboilerplate.webcomm.com.au/)

I've installed comapass, sass, converted css to scss, wrote custom layout and template files in `app/design/frontend`, but it didn't work. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Checked your code on git hub,

I see the two folder

```
app
skin
```

Copy whole folder to you theme root folders.

if all done the Refresh your cache.

No Set the Theme in backend .

**Step 1 :**  login into your Magento admin Panel.

**Step 2 :**  Go to System >> Configuration >> General >> Desig.

**Step 3 :** Open First Tab Set Package. Enter your theme name same as "waterlee-boilerplate"

**Step 4 :** Save your configuration.

**Step 5 :** Now you can see your theme on site.

Comment: I did that.... What I am trying is writing my own custom theme, maybe something like this, http://themeforest.net/item/offbeat-responsive-multipurpose-theme/6913036....

Comment: good :) ...........

Comment: Should I write custom layout and template codes? Or should I copy them from base folder and modify them?

Comment: no don't do that don't copy in base folder

Comment: Copy the template files that you need to customise from your base to your theme folder...

Comment: yes that is the proper way or you can crate local.xml file in your theme folder and put your custom code in that file

Comment: Yes, it is best to use a local.xml file in your themes layout folder and leave the base layout XML files untouched.